# VBA using xpath on Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, xpath

Trying to use this command to fill a string. I have status defined as a string in a custom type. This command is not working though as I keep getting an "Object does not support this property or method" error.

WOInfo.Status = Document.getXPathElement("//div[@id='pnlTitle']/table/tbody/tr/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApD3A.png)/span/text()")

[image: DOM Snapshot]

Comment: There's no context for that line of code, so it's difficult to make any suggestion.  What are `Document` and `WOInfo` here?  What is `getXPathElement` - Google only has references which point to a function in VBA for translating an XPath to a document element.  It's not a method of `Document`...

Comment: "td[0]" would be the first data row, yet you highlight the second (1).

Comment: Whoops should've been td[1] - still does not fix the issue. WOInfo is a custom type I created - no error there. @TimWilliams are you saying I need to import the getXpathElement function?

Comment: I guess I'm asking where you got that code from?